# Powershell scriptopen a window and send command to window

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to open a CMD as system using PowerShell and then send a command to that system window.
what i've got so far is this:

```
$opensystempromt = '"/c PsExec.exe -is cmd.exe'
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start('cmd.exe',$opensystempromt)
$systemcommand = 'CustomerService.exe deploy aa.txt bb.txt'
```

what i can't figure out is how to send the system command to the newly opened CMD.
and there's no documentation for it anywhere, that i could find

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Start-Process` to open cmd.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList {/k Insert your variables here}
```

with `-verb runas` you'll open cmd as an administrator. `ArgumentList` is your "command part". `/k` leaves the cmd open, after the commands are done. If you want cmd to close instead, use `/c`.